# Total days error

Tags: php

when start date  ex:6/1/2016 and 
end date ex : 8/1/2016

It is the process by computational days, so the process is the result of 3 days
6/1/2016 day
7/1/2016 day
8/1/2016 day

This is wrong .

Must be 6/1/2016 to 7/1/2016 day and 7/1/2016 to 8/1/2016 day

so the sum 2 day not 3 days

```
 $start_date = strtotime($date_from);
    $end_date   = strtotime($date_to);

    $datetime1 = date_create($date_from);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date_to);
    $interval  = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    $cs_booking_days = $interval->days;

    // Loop between timestamps, 24 hours at a time
    $total_price = '';
    $adult_price = 0;

    $pricings           = get_option('cs_price_options');
    $cs_offers_options  = get_option("cs_offers_options");

    $pricings_array     = $pricings[$post_id];

    if (isset($pricings[$post_id]['cs_plan_days'])) {
        $cs_sp_days = $pricings[$post_id]['cs_plan_days'];
    }

    $pricing_data           = array();
    $brk_counter            = 0;
    $total_orignal          = 0;
    $price['total_price']   = 0;
    $flag                   = false;

    for ($i = $start_date; $i <= $end_date; $i = $i + 86400) {

        $total_days++;
        $brk_counter++;
        $thisDate = date('Y-m-d', $i); // 2010-05-01, 2010-05-02, etc
        $day      = strtolower(date('D', strtotime($thisDate)));

        $adult_price = $pricings_array['cs_pricing_branches']['adult_' . $day . '_price'][0];


        $adult_temp_price   = $adult_price != '' ? $adult_price : 0;
        $adult_price        = $adult_temp_price;
        $to_check_date      = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $i));
```

Comment: is there a question lurking here perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// your code goes here

$startTimeStamp = strtotime("2016/01/06");
$endTimeStamp = strtotime("2016/01/08");

$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);

$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

// and you might want to convert to integer
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);

echo $numberDays;
```

http://ideone.com/8miDiP

**Back to your code => Replace**

```
for ($i = $start_date; $i <= $end_date; $i = $i + 86400) {
```

**this**

```
for ($i = $start_date; $i < $end_date; $i = $i + 86400) {
```

**<=** is problem, type **<**

**EXPLANATION**

06.01 - 08.01

First loop:
$i = 06.01 and <= 08.01

Second loop:
$i = 07.01 and <= 08.01

Third loop:
$i = 08.01 and <= 08.01 - STILL TRUE, so SUM = 3 days

After change

First loop:
$i = 06.01 and < 08.01

Second loop:
$i = 07.01 and < 08.01

Third loop:
$i = 08.01 and < 08.01 - NOW FALSE, so SUM = 2 days

Comment: Thank you for help me :)

Comment: Mark as resolved and comment as helpfull :) Enjoy :)